BitmapFactory.decodeStream() no longer works with GIFs in SDK 35?
For a long time I've been using Picasso to load images into my ImageView. I noticed that on newer devices (Android 35+) the behaviour of BitmapFactory.decodeStream() has changed to now return null for image/gif mime types. This affects Picasso as well as several other Image loading/caching libraries.
An example resource that is affected by this can be found here:
https://assets.amuniversal.com/2c394c300ede013d5a13005056a9545d
While this is a gif, it is a single frame gif and somehow decodeStream() was previously able to convert this into a Bitmap.
Is this intended or a regression? What would be the best way to work around this change? Convert the GIF to frames and take the first one?
